# Issue with OAuth authentication for the new Basecamp Api using OAConsumer

Tags: ios, api, oauth, basecamp

My code looks something like this :

```
OAConsumer *consumer = [[OAConsumer alloc] initWithKey:@"my_ClientID"
                                                secret:@"my_Secret"];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://launchpad.37signals.com/authorization/token"];

OAMutableURLRequest *request = [[OAMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url
                                                               consumer:consumer
                                                                  token:nil   // we don't have a Token yet
                                                                  realm:nil   // our service provider doesn't specify a realm
                                                      signatureProvider:nil]; // use the default method, HMAC-SHA1

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSLog(@"USER URL : %@",[request URL]);
OADataFetcher *fetcher = [[OADataFetcher alloc] init]; 

[fetcher fetchDataWithRequest:request
                     delegate:self
            didFinishSelector:@selector(requestTokenTicket:didFinishWithData:)
              didFailSelector:@selector(requestTokenTicket:didFailWithError:)];
```

.

```
- (void)requestTokenTicket:(OAServiceTicket *)ticket didFinishWithData:(NSData *)data {
    if (ticket.didSucceed) {
        NSString *responseBody = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data
                                                       encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        OAToken *requestToken = [[OAToken alloc] initWithHTTPResponseBody:responseBody];
        NSLog(@"%@",requestToken);
    }
}
```

My Delegate method never gets a (ticket.didSucceed) Success.

Can someone tell me what I am missing here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to have the user authorize your app and generate the token for the first time. For this, you're using the wrong URL. From the [37Signals API](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/37signals-api/hrDaUhNMG34):

> 1. Your app requests authorization by redirecting your user to Launchpad:
>        https://launchpad.37signals.com/authorization/new?type=web_server&client_id=your-client-id&redirect_uri=your-redirect-uri

The URL you are using is for getting the access token from the verification code.

Comment: @Mark S. and shyambhat Can you give me some time , I need your help regarding Basecamp Next Api's. Email is : khalid0491@gmail.com Thanks